# Is it OK to use reactive streams for synchronous operations?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming

If I want to map/filter/whatever some collection I already have, is it OK to use reactive streams for that?

For example, I'd like to do something like this in Android (using RxAndroid and gradle-retrolambda):

```
List<Product> availableProducts =
    Observable.from(products)
        .filter(p -> p.isAvailable())
        .toSortedList((p1,p2) -> p1.getPrice() - p2.getPrice())
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
```

Is this OK? Should I do it other way? Is it a bad practice? If so, why do we have `toBlocking`?

Thank you

Comment: Something has to eventually block somewhere for anything to get done. I don't see a problem with what you have

Comment: Thank you cricket_007. I've read somewhere that in rx you should keep everything non-blocking. I can subscribe to the observable as usual but I see that `toBlocking` makes the code simpler (similar to Java8 streams) and, like you, I don't see a problem in this case, because the code won't actually block.

Comment: In this case the code will block, though. Same as when it blocks for the subscription event handling